# Как отцентрировать .navbar-nav в бутстрапе?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

НЕ совсем понимаю как содержимое установить по центру

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria- 
 expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Главная<span class="sr-only"> 
 (current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Галлерея</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Обо мне</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">События</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Наша Школа</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Нормативы</a>
        </li>

     </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте к `navbar-nav` уже существующие в бутстрапе классы: `w-100` и `justify-content-center`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria- expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Главная<span class="sr-only"> 
 (current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Галлерея</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Обо мне</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">События</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Наша Школа</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Нормативы</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

К UL добавить класс:

```
.nav-centered {
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;}
```

Как то так:

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav nav-centered">
```